# Query using DTO objects in C#

Tags: c#, dto

I am quite new to this. I am trying to use dto objects to query database. I used the EntitiestoDTO generator addin.

This is the dto code.

```
[DataContract()]
public partial class UserInfoDTO
{
    [DataMember()]
    public String UniqueNo { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String DisplayName { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String LoginPass { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String CompanyEmail { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public Boolean IsaMember { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public Nullable<DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public List<CompanyUserRoleDTO> CompanyUserRoles { get; set; }

    public UserInfoDTO()
    {
    }

    public UserInfoDTO(String UniqueNo, String userName, String firstName, String lastName, String displayName, String loginPass, String email, String companyEmail, Boolean isaMember, String createdBy, String updatedBy, DateTime createdDate, Nullable<DateTime> updatedDate, List<CompanyUserRoleDTO> companyUserRoles)
    {
        this.UniqueNo = UniqueNo;
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.DisplayName = displayName;
        this.LoginPass = loginPass;
        this.Email = email;
        this.CompanyEmail = companyEmail;
        this.IsaMember = isaMember;
        this.CreatedBy = createdBy;
        this.UpdatedBy = updatedBy;
        this.CreatedDate = createdDate;
        this.UpdatedDate = updatedDate;
        this.CompanyUserRoles = companyUserRoles;
    }
}
}
```

My Business Layer is a different project. How do I build a method to query and get the userInfo by passing the parameter UniqueNo?

Comment: this is way to broad - what you want is basically a todo or introduction into EF - have you tried your fav. search machine or a good book? - make sure you have a look at StackOverflows FAQ too

Comment: You will need to write a DAO Layer which accesses the DB using these objects. This is a whole topic in itself. Search for tutorials on `Entity Framework`, `Linq to SQL`, `Linq to Objects`, and other related terms. If you get stuck at some point, try asking specific targeted questions. See [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints).